# c# Core System.Management.Automation remote connection error

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

I am attempting to write a C# core program to run powershell scripts on remote linux systems. Running on .net core is a requirement for this project. I am trying to loosely follow a guide I found on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/773685/Enable-Remote-PowerShell-Execution-in-Csharp).

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SSHConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new SSHConnectionInfo(userName: "user", computerName: "server", keyFilePath: "id_rsa");


            using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
            {
                runspace.Open(); // The program errors out here
                runspace.Close();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have the "id_rsa" file located int the same folder as the program. I have verified that openssh for windows, powershell core 6.0.2, and .net core 2 SDK are installed and working. I am using the following nuget packages from the [Microsoft Powershell Core repository](https://powershell.myget.org/F/powershell-core/api/v3/index.json): Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK (6.0.2) and Sytem.Managment.Automation (6.0.2)

This is the error I am receiving:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingDataStructureException: An error has occurred which PowerShell cannot handle. A remote session might have ended. ---> System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
Parameter name: path
   at System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(String path)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SSHConnectionInfo.StartSSHProcess(StreamWriter& stdInWriterVar, StreamReader& stdOutReaderVar, StreamReader& stdErrReaderVar)
   at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.Client.SSHClientSessionTransportManager.CreateAsync()
   at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.ClientRemoteSessionDSHandlerImpl.SendNegotiationAsync(RemoteSessionState sessionState)
   at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.ClientRemoteSessionDSHandlerImpl.HandleStateChanged(Object sender, RemoteSessionStateEventArgs arg)
   at System.Management.Automation.ExtensionMethods.SafeInvoke[T](EventHandler`1 eventHandler, Object sender, T eventArgs)
   at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.ClientRemoteSessionDSHandlerStateMachine.RaiseStateMachineEvents()
   at System.Management.Automation.Remoting.ClientRemoteSessionDSHandlerStateMachine.ProcessEvents()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AsyncResult.EndInvoke()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Internal.RunspacePoolInternal.EndOpen(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Internal.RemoteRunspacePoolInternal.Open()
   at System.Management.Automation.RemoteRunspace.Open()
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 18
Press any key to continue . . .
```

At this point I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up opening an [issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7252) on github for this error. To work around this issue currently you will need to add the following code to your program until this [issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7763) gets resolved in a future version of powershell core (>6.0.4 or >6.1.0-rc.1). [Here is the specific post regarding the issue.](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7252#issuecomment-420405006)

```
if (System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace.DefaultRunspace == null)
{
    var defaultRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    defaultRunspace.Open();
    System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace.DefaultRunspace = defaultRunspace;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following *answer* is derived from the [Bruc3 work-around answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52284212/3519108) and the [RemoteRunspace Sample 01](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powershell-sdk-samples/tree/master/SDK-3.0) from the Powershell SDK.

```
namespace Sample.PowerShell.Runspace
{
  using System;
  using System.Management.Automation;
  using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

  /// <summary>
  /// This class contains the Main enrty point for the application.
  /// </summary>
  internal class SshRemoteRunspace
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      SSHConnectionInfo sshConnectionInfo = new 
      SSHConnectionInfo("Administrator", "remote-hyper-v-server.mydomain.com", @"C:\Users\myself\.ssh\id_ed25519.pub");

      // Bruc3 Workaround
      if (System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace.DefaultRunspace is null)
      {
        var defaultRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        defaultRunspace.Open();
        System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace.DefaultRunspace = defaultRunspace;
      }

      // Create a remote runspace using the connection information.
      using (Runspace remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(sshConnectionInfo))
      {
        remoteRunspace.Open();

        // Powershell command
        using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Get-VMReplication"))
        {
          // makes the Powershell command run in the remote runspace instead of locally
          powershell.Runspace = remoteRunspace;

          // display the results in the local console
          foreach (PSObject result in powershell.Invoke())
          {
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
          }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to exit > ");
        Console.ReadKey();
        remoteRunspace.Close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```